# SQL Server table not updating

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
 "WITH CTE AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNumber, Name, Website, Username, Password, Extras, CategoryIn" +
 "FROM Accounts WHERE CategoryIn = @category) " +
 "UPDATE CTE SET Name = @name, Website = @website, Username = @username, Password = @password, Extras = @extras, CategoryIn = @category WHERE RowNumber = @id", connection))
{ 
    connection.Open();

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", category);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@website", website);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@extras", extras);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I have this bit of code to update the table and it updates fine for all except the column `CategoryIn`. I'm guessing it has something to do with the CTE and the `WHERE CategoryIn = @category` part. Can someone direct me please?

Comment: What do you mean by _not updating_? You get any exception or error message? Is it update in your sql server?

Comment: It seems that you are using the same parameter for the WHERE and the SET- Don't you need a "BEFORE" and "AFTER" values for that CategoryIn field?

Comment: @Steve Ahh yes, how silly of me. I've got it working now thanks so much!

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the info, that is quite interesting